# Incrementing value in array of tuples

Tags: python

I have an array of integers. I want to create the second array of tuples using values from the first array and index of them, so it should look like `[(0,3), (1,4), (2,8), (3,1)]`.

I tried this:

```
key1=0
for tabd in raw_data.demand_array:
    print (tabd)
    demands.append((key1,tabd))
    key1=+1
```

But the first value (key1) is incremented only once and result is: `[(0,3), (1,4), (1,8), (1,1)]`.
What's the reason for it and how can I repair it?

Comment: there is a typo in your code. =+ should be +=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use almost exactly your same code, but fix the typo.

```
key1=0
for tabd in raw_data.demand_array:
    print (tabd)
    demands.append((key1,tabd))
    key1 += 1
```

Note it is `+=` not `=+`

Answer (score 2):

The [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr = [3,4,8,1]

print([(_index, num) for _index, num in enumerate(arr)])
```

Output:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 8), (3, 1)]
```